# Multiple mysql 'select from' in one query

Tags: mysql

> SELECT (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id=1) AS user_id, (SELECT usersetting_user_id FROM usersettings WHERE usersetting_user_id=1) AS usersetting_user_id;

this returns:

```
| user_id | usersetting_user_id |  
|       1 |                   1 |
```

but I want to display all users, not just one. So I run the following:

> SELECT (SELECT user_id FROM users) AS user_id, (SELECT usersetting_user_id FROM usersettings) AS usersetting_user_id;``

and get:

```
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Any idea how to circumvent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a `join` statement, like so:

```
SELECT u.user_id, us.usersetting_user_id
FROM users u
JOIN usersettings us ON u.user_id = us.usersetting_user_id
```

This assumes usersettings.usersetting_user_id is a reference to the primary key (user_id) of users. Specifics can be found [in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Comment: Thanks, it works. Don't understand what's with the "u" and "us" but I'll read the manual. EDIT: so those are aliases, ok.

Comment: u and us are aliases for the tables users and usersettings

Comment: Sorry about that, I should've noted that below the example. Aliases aren't required, you could just as well use "users.user_id" instead of "u.user_id" without them, but it leads to excessively long queries when you start adding more tables.

Answer (score 2):

Assign aliases in `FROM` clause, then use `alias.fieldname`. Also group `SELECT` and `FROM` parts

```
SELECT user_id.user_id, usersetting_user_id.usersetting_user_id
FROM users AS user_id, usersettings AS usersetting_user_id;
```

Comment: aah ok, so those are aliases. thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend to use in queries like this Joins or multiple froms because you loading all tables at all and then filtering it.
It's like using Having instead of Where.
It's related on mysql-server version but you can compare it byself with EXPLAIN (or EXPLAIN EXTENDED).

In your case I recommend you to use one table in from directive (basic table, users for example), and load other data with inner queries with Where id=user_id.

```
# query with basic table only
SELECT
  user_id
FROM users AS u;
# extended query
SELECT
  user_id,
  (SELECT usersetting_user_id
    FROM usersettings
    WHERE usersetting_user_id = u.user_id) AS usersetting_user_id
FROM users AS u;
```

P.s. If you know that your tables have the same rows count you can use the solution with Join by Tzarium but as INNER/LEFT/RIGHT JOIN instead of JOIN or OUTER JOIN.